# pointer operation ++ causes memory leak?

Tags: c++

when I write

```
char *s = "hello everyone";
s++;
```

is there memory leak here?

p/s: English is not my native language so can have some errors.

Comment: That shouldn't even compile; it should be `const char* s = "hello everyone";`

Answer (score 6):

No, string literals are not allocated, so there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no leak there and it has nothing to do with the pointer pointing at a string literal.  Incrementing a pointer will NEVER cause a memory leak.  The only thing that causes memory leaks is not freeing memory that you allocate.